# How to send values of a form from jsp to java

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, javabeans

I have a form which has 30 different fields. As passing them all to the controller need to have an attribute for each along with a pair of getter, setters.

I am going to make the form fields as an object and send the object to the controller.

I am using the following code ****but some people suggest its a bad practice to call a java method from jsp and use JSTL instead, but do not know how to implement it using JSTL. 
Is there any other method to do it?****

My JSP

```
 <s:form>
 code to implement form goes here
 </s:form> 

<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.User"/>

    <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>

      <%
         String myoutput = myController.Xclass(obj);
         out.print(myoutput);
         if(myController.Xclass(obj).equals("output"))
            {
               out.print("The form is successfully submitted.");
            }
      %>
```

The controller

```
  public String Xclass(User obj){
           return "output";
        }
```

To clarify my class diagram is a following:

```
User Class {
 all the attributes and getters setters
}

myController class extends User {

    public String XClass(User obj){
       ... work on the inputes ...
      return "output";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to do that logic inside the JSP?  Why can't you do it inside the controller?

Comment: @tieTYT, as I explained I have 30 different fields, if I do not send them as an object I have to have all the attributes in my controller, but in this case I can extend a class which has all the attributes.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: @Bdloul, I know JSTL is better but not sure how to implement it, I mean send the inputs to java in other way.

Comment: You don't send objects to a controller. This is HTTP; you send strings. Because S2 does type conversion it *looks* like you're sending an object--but you're not. As I said, if your concern is the number of properties in your controller, you can make a POJO and expose it manually or via ModelDriven.

Comment: I also think you're misunderstanding how JSP works: it is evaluated *on the server* before ever getting to the client. The only thing the client knows about is HTML, JavaScript, CSS, etc.

Comment: would you give me an example of exposing the pojo ? I am confused !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of action properties is the issue, expose a POJO manually, or use [ModelDriven](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/model-driven.html).

Doing it manually is simple, for example:

```java
public class UserController {
    private User user; // Plus public getter and setter
}
```

Then in the JSP you can refer to `User` properties by name:

```xml
<s:form ...>
  <s:textfield key="user.firstName"/>
  ...
```

Using `ModelDriven` is theoretically even easier, since it's put on the stack automagically. It can be tricky to make sure new models are instantiated only when required, but basically (from memory):

```java
public class UserController implements ModelDriven<User> {
    private User user;
    public User getModel() { return user; }
}
```

Use the `User` properties directly in the JSP since the `User` is pushed on the stack:

```xml
<s:form ...>
  <s:textfield key="firstName"/>
  ...
```

Similarly, on form submission, a model is created and used as the first target of methods.

Please remember that you never send objects to the Java side: you always, and only, send strings (from normal HTTP form submissions). There may be magic on the server side that transforms those strings into objects, but it's just that: magic. Magic and hope.